# Why sys.exit() cannot stop to execute the next line of script Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

**Target** : If the **file do not exist** , **stop run the next script**

**Code** :

```
import glob ,os , sys
FL = []
for i in FL:
    if os.path.isfile(i):
        print("file exist")
    else:
        print("no such a file")
        sys.exit("check the errors before run the NEXT script")

print("This is the NEXT script")
```

**Problem** : Still return the result as

```
"This is the NEXT script"
```

**Environment** : Python 3.7 , Jupyter

Do i misunderstood the usage of sys.exit() ?

- Since there are over 100 of lines to run if the files EXIST ,
  thus i am avoiding put them all into the if TRUE statement loops.
  Welcome to point out if this mindset itself also a conceptual 
  mistake programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

```
FL = []
for i in FL:
    something
```

This will *never* execute `something` simply because the `FL` collection is empty. You are asking it do so something for each element in an empty list so obviously, it does it *zero* times.

---

What you need to do is to detect an empty list and handle that separately. You could do that by checking `len(FL)` beforehand, but Python has a nifty feature of the `for` loop  that can be used to detect when the loop processed no items. This is the `for..else` feature.

Consider the code:

```
import sys
FL = []
for i in FL:
    print(i)
else:
    sys.exit("empty")
print("remainder")
```

This prints each item in the list but exits if there were none in it.

---

In terms of applying that to *your* code, it would be something like:

```
import glob ,os , sys
FL = []
for i in FL:
    if os.path.isfile(i):
        print(i, "file exists")
    else:
        print("no such file", i)
        sys.exit("check the errors before run the NEXT script")
else:
    print("no files in list")
    sys.exit("check the errors before run the NEXT script")

print("This is the NEXT script")
```

Comment: thankyou your explanation  help a lot . Actually it was collecting a list of file to run another processing . `FL = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.csv"))` , If they are not exist , stop run : `print("This is the NEXT script")` , if they exist , run the next script : `print("This is the NEXT script")`.